# node.js sails.js waterline bluebird .then and .spread

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to figure out how promises work in sails, and have been successful passing data from waterline queries via .then, but have not been able to utilize .spread. I am getting a function not defined error. Any suggestions how the first section of code can be improved to work?

```
 //results in error
    Promise.all([Xyz.find(), Abc.find()]).spread(function (someOtherResult, yetAnotherResult) {
        console.log(someOtherResult)
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

The following work but would be either trickier to extract data from, or require excessively long nested .then clauses:

```
    Promise.all([Xyz.find(), Abc.find()]).then(function (results) {
        console.log(results[0][1]);
        console.log(results[0].length);
    })


    Abc.find().then(function (foundAbcs) {
        Promise.all(Xyz.find().then(function (foundXyzs) {
            console.log(foundAbcs);
            console.log(foundXyzs);
            // additional syncranouse logic with Abc and Xyz
        }))
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, very simple mistake, I didn't realize I needed:

var Promise = require('bluebird');

prior to module.exports in sails.js .11, problem solved.